# Android Paging 3 is not loading next page

Tags: android-paging, android-paging-3, android-paging-library

After migrating from custom paging implementation to *Jetpack Paging 3 library*,
data is not loading as expected.
The **first page is handled correctly** according to the `PagingConfig` of `Pager`:

```kotlin
internal fun createProductListPager(pagingSource: ProductListPagingSource): Pager<Int, Product> = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 10,
        prefetchDistance = 2,
    ),
    initialKey = 0,
) { pagingSource }
```

Here is an extract of the `Adapter`:

```kotlin
public class PagingProductCardAdapter(private val viewBinder: CoreViewBinder) :
    PagingDataAdapter<Listable, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(viewBinder.getDiffUtils()) {


    public val list: List<Listable>
        get() = snapshot().items


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      // ...
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewBinder.bind(list[position], holder)
    }
    // ...
}
```

When scrolling to the bottom of the RecyclerView, the next page is **not loaded at all** (No call to `PagingSource.load()`)
What can go wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How does the `PagingSource` know when to load more data? What magic is behind it?
Well, it turns out that **the Adapter is responsible for this**.
How can the `Adapter` be aware of loaded data?
You have to call `getItem()` as documented:

```kotlin
/**
 * Returns the presented item at the specified position, notifying Paging of the item access to
 * trigger any loads necessary to fulfill [prefetchDistance][PagingConfig.prefetchDistance].
 *
 * @param position Index of the presented item to return, including placeholders.
 * @return The presented item at [position], `null` if it is a placeholder
 */
protected fun getItem(@IntRange(from = 0) position: Int) = differ.getItem(position)
```

As we were accessing the entire list via snapshot:

```kotlin
public val list: List<Listable>
    get() = snapshot().items
```

the Adapter couldn't know what item was being loaded, and couldn't trigger the next page loading.

So the fix is:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    getItem(position)?.let {
        viewBinder.bind(list[position], holder)
    }
}
```

With this, everything is working properly!

Comment: I've spent 5 hours on this issue, but thanks to @Nico for providing the answer. It saved me a lot of time.